# Python code throw error when I try to run our python code

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
n2=np.zeros((5,5))

error=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python Program\numpy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "f:\Python Program\numpy.py", line 2, in <module>
    n1= np.zeros((3,3))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Don't call your script the same as your libraries!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried reinstalling numpy ?

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```